# Не работает assign в string, но работает +=

Tags: c++, строки

Через assign бывает работает правильно, то есть добавляет к существующему, а бывает просто перезаписывает, а через += всегда хорошо. 
Не работает (перезаписывает) код примерно такой:

```
string namebuffer;
for(list<vector<string> > :: iterator i = m_AccPassList.begin(); i != m_AccPassList.end(); i++)
namebuffer.assign( (*i)[0] );
```

А если `namebuffer+= (*i)[0];`, то работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы перепутали assign и append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/

Assigns a new value to the string, **replacing its current contents**.

assign именно перезаписывает содержимое. Если нужна конкатенация, т.е. объединение строк, то используете оператор "+".